# Which way to go with graphic-intense multi-touch app, XNA or WPF?

Tags: wpf, xna, multi-touch

I am about to start development of a multi-touch application.
I need to decide between WPF and XNA.
Which would run faster ?
WPF already has libraries to support multi-touch via TUIO input.
Does anyone know a similar library or even just sample code to 
drag/rotate/move objects in XNA ?

Thanks!
SW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch is just another way of getting input from the user. Whether you route this input to an XNA app or WPF app depends more on what you want to do in the app.

XNA is a lower level api for doing 2D/3D on Windows, Xbox and Zune. WPF has only a higher level support for doing 3D and targets (currently) only Windows. So going with XNA vs WPF is imo more a decision of graphics requirements and platform support.

Since your app is graphic intense it could be more efficient to work at a lower level (read XNA or even [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)/[DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx)). [Reimer's XNA tutorials](http://www.riemers.net) have a lot of great articles for starting out with XNA.

Answer (score 1):

If you use XNA, you're going to be doing a *lot* of math to manually analyze the touch information - I'd check out WPF first (or perhaps you can host XNA visuals *inside* WPF and use WPF's touch input engine)

Answer (score 0):

The [Bespoke MultiTouch Framework](http://www.bespokesoftware.org/wordpress/?page_id=41) supports multitouch and XNA together.  Paul has a number of XNA samples already built to demonstrate the features you are looking for :-)