# Multi-touch events in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I need to apply multi touch events together(vertical drag,horizontal drag) in xna. If any one knows please help.

Comment: I think I need to open a request on meta to change **Title** to **Question Title** so it's clear what kind of title it's supposed to be.

Comment: @BoltClock: had to laugh at that comment, though shouldn't the watermark be enough? One would think anyways...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914901/which-way-to-go-with-graphic-intense-multi-touch-app-xna-or-wpf

Comment: @Brad Christie: You mean the placeholder text "what's your programming question"? Yeah, I was thinking the same...

Comment: @BoltClock: Please don't! It makes me laugh _every time_.

Comment: @Rekha: I assume this is for WP7? If you're trying to do this on a PC, I'm afraid you'll be disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

I use the gesture as horizontal, vertical drag, this is an example :

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
  GestureSample gesture =TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
  if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.VerticalDrag)
  {
     //insert the code here that execute when the event is detected
  }
}
```

this is the code in your update or your thread, however, you must declare this in your class

`TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.VerticalDrag;`